# How to set a component host name with data binding

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My component has a variable which is called `componentId` which is defined as an input of the component:

```
@Input() public componentId: string;
```

I want this variable to be interpreted when building the HTML, in order to assign it to the attribute`name`. Something like this:

```
<customTag name="{{componentId}}"/>
```

The issue is that `customTag` has no property `name`, so when I try to do that I get the exception:

```
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'customTag'.
```

However, if I was doing this:

```
<customTag name="somename"/>
```

... in the rendered HTML I can correctly see the attribute name filled with "somename".

What I need is just to use the value of this variable (`componentId`) as a `name` of `customTag`, without need of actually trying to access the property `name` of the component `customTag` (on which's code I've no control since it comes from a library).

How can I just read the value of `componentId` to assign it dynamically to the static attribute `name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding):

```
<customTag [attr.name]="componentId"></customTag>
```

Comment: It worked! I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes (doesn't let me yet), thanks a lot!